# SSO/Authorisation - Can I override the app name?

Tags: android, google-plus, google-account

When I use Google Plus/SSO, I see the authorisation screen. There it displays my app name - which is a shortened version of the full product name.

Is there any way I can override the app name in the authorisation screen without renaming my app?

Answer (score 1):

From the [Google Developer Console](https://console.developer.google.com), select consent screen from the left navigation:

[image: Navigation with consent selected]

From there, you can change the application name and other aspects of the consent screen:
[image]

Comment: I've double checked - the full app name is set in the Consent Screen. However, the Google sign in screen doesn't show this string - it shows the name of the Android app

Comment: Got it, I'll see if I can find out more.

Comment: Camel, Can you check and make sure the client ID you're using with your app on iOS matches the client ID  specified for your iOS app in the developer's console? It sounds like maybe you are using your Android app's client ID.